# Title in nested ASP.NET Master Pages

Tags: asp.net, master-pages

I'm unable to set the **tab title** of my ASP.NET pages.

I have nested master pages. I can set tab icon successfully, but the title always show "Home Page".  What am I doing wrong?

```
    <%@ Master Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true"  CodeBehind="Topbar.master.cs" Inherits="WebApplication1.Masters.Topbar"  %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title>SomeTitle</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />   
    <link href="~/Styles/public.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />    
    <link rel="Shortcut Icon" href="~/Images/ionicon.ico" />

    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="head" runat="server">
    </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>

</head>
<body>
```

....

```
    <%@ Master Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Masters/Topbar.Master" AutoEventWireup="true"
    CodeBehind="Public.Master.cs" Inherits="WebApplication1.PublicMaster" %>

<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" runat="server">
    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="head" runat="server">


    </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
</asp:Content>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

On the content page you should be using a @Page directive, in which you can set the page title:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Master1.master" 
     AutoEventWireup="true" Title="Untitled Page"  %>
```

Comment: Ah! I see I had that already, set to "Home Page", it overrides the master <title> tag.  cheers!  :)

Answer (score 1):

You can also do it from server side by keeping this block in master page code file

```
string pageNM = Request.Url.ToString();
 if (pageNM.Contains("index.aspx"))
 {
 this.Page.Title = "My custom Index Page Title";
 }
```